# Make a typeahead remote call to codeigniter controller

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, typeahead.js

I want to be able to make a remote data call from bloodhound using typeahead to model with codeigniter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I was struggling a bit trying to get typeahead (twitter) remote data and codeigniter to work together, I dint't find a good example that fit with my needs. After a few hours I came up with the following code, hope it helps.

**The View:**

```
var proyectos = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: function(d) { return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.proyecto_titulo); },
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  remote: {
    url: 'proyectos/proyectos/getProyectos?query=%QUERY',
    wildcard: '%QUERY'
  } 
});

$('#titulo').typeahead({
    hint: true,
    highlight: true,
    minLength: 3
 },
  {
  name: 'proyectos',
  displayKey: 'proyecto_titulo',
  source: proyectos.ttAdapter(),
  templates: {
    empty: [
      '<div class="empty-message">',
        'No se encontraron registros que coincidan con la búsqueda.',
      '</div>'
    ].join('\n'),
    suggestion: Handlebars.compile('<p>{{proyecto_titulo}} – <strong>{{tipo_proyecto_nombre}}</strong> </p>')
  }
});
```

The relevant part here is:

*remote: {
        url: 'proyectos/proyectos/getProyectos?query=%QUERY',
        wildcard: '%QUERY'
      }*

Where **proyectos/proyectos** is the controller path and **getProyectos** is the method that answers the request.

Whenever you type, and based on the **minLength** setting, is going to request a matching string in the back-end.

Note: In order to use the **suggestion** part in the **templates** setting, you must download the **handlebars.js** library.

**The Controller:**

```
public function getProyectos() {
        $consulta = $this->input->get('query');
        $proyectos = $this->proyectos_model->getProyectos($consulta);
        if($proyectos->num_rows() > 0){
            echo json_encode($proyectos->result());
        }
        else{
            echo '';
        }
    }
```

We first get the query string from the view with **$this->input->get('query')** and afterwards pass it to our model.

**The Model:**

```
public function getProyectos($consulta) {
         $query = $this->db->query
        ("select pro.proyecto_id
                ,pro.proyecto_titulo
                ,tip.tipo_proyecto_nombre
                ,tip.tipo_proyecto_id
                from proyectos pro 
                inner join tipos_proyectos tip on tip.tipo_proyecto_id = pro.tipo_proyecto_id 
                where pro.proyecto_titulo ilike '%" . $consulta . "%' ");
        return $query;
     }
```

Here in the model we simply pass the query string to our sql select statement and we're done. The database I'm using is postgresql.

I hope you find this helpful.